# How to register a collection conditionally using Simple Injector?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I'm trying to register the following combination in Simple Injector:

1. Collection of (one or more) implementations of `IMyInterface` for a concrete type, e.g. `Implementation1<MyClass>` and `Implementation2<MyClass>` for `IMyInterface<MyClass>`
2. Dummy collection (empty list) for the *open generic* type `IMyInterface<T>` as fall-back (conditional?)

This way I want to ensure that all requestors of `IEnumerable<IMyInterface<T>>` will get at least an empty list or the list of real implementations; requestor of `IEnumerable<IMyInterface<MyClass>>` should get enumerable instance (e.g. `List<IMyInterface<MyClass>>`) with the elements `Implementation1<MyClass>` and `Implementation2<MyClass>`, and requestor of `IEnumerable<IMyInterface<AnotherClass>>` should get `Enumerable.Empty<IMyInterface<AnotherClass>>`.

The list of classes is not fixed in the registration code. I've implemented a bootstrapper collecting all implementations from assemblies.

I tried using several combinations of `RegisterCollection` and `RegisterConditional`, but no one fulfilled all requirements.
Is there a work-around for (not existing) RegisterCollectionConditional?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/283

Comment: Can you explain (or show) what the conditions are for the implementations to show up in the collection or not?

Comment: Without that info it is impossible to supply you with a good answer.

Comment: @Steven, thans for your response! I think Issue 283 is not releated, because I'm working with an open generic collection. I've reworked the question description, hopefully with the requested inforamtion.

Comment: You state that `IEnumerable<IMyInterface<AnotherClass>>` should be an empty list, while `IEnumerable<IMyInterface<MyClass>>` should have two implementations. But what are the exact conditions on which you wish to make `IEnumerable<IMyInterface<AnotherClass>>` empty? Do you have any type constraints on `Implementation1<T>` and `Implementation2<T>` that prevent `Implementation1<AnotherClass>` to be a valid type?

Comment: `Implementation1` (and Implementation2) are NOT open generic, but closed for `MyClass`. I do not want to register open generic implementations, but closed implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated with v4.3 syntax.**

What you want to do does not require anything special in Simple Injector; Simple Injector will *automatically* select any assignable type for you. Assuming the following types:

```
class Implementation1 : IMyInterface<MyClass> { }
class Implementation2 : IMyInterface<MyClass> { }
class Implementation3 : IMyInterface<FooBarClass>, IMyInterface<MyClass> { }
```

The registration would look as follows:

```
container.Collection.Register(typeof(IMyInterface<>),
    typeof(Implementation1),
    typeof(Implementation2),
    typeof(Implementation3));
```

This will result in the following:

```
// returns: Implementation1, Implementation2, Implementation3.
container.GetAllInstances<IMyInterface<MyClass>>();

// returns: Implementation3.
container.GetAllInstances<IMyInterface<FooBarClass>>();


// returns: empty list.
container.GetAllInstances<IMyInterface<AnotherClass>>();
```

Instead of registering all types manually, you can also use batch registration:

```
container.Collection.Register(typeof(IMyInterface<>),
    typeof(Implementation1).Assembly);
```

This will register all implementations (assuming they are all in the same assembly).

In case however you have the following types:

```
class Implementation1<T> : IMyInterface<T> { }
class Implementation2<T> : IMyInterface<T> { }
class Implementation3<T> : IMyInterface<T> { }
```

You can do the following registration:

```
container.Collection.Register(typeof(IMyInterface<>),
    typeof(Implementation1<MyClass>),
    typeof(Implementation2<MyClass>),
    typeof(Implementation3<MyClass>),
    typeof(Implementation3<FooBarClass>));
```

This registration would result in the same result as we've seen before:

```
// returns: Implementation1<MyClass>, Implementation2<MyClass>, Implementation3<MyClass>.
container.GetAllInstances<IMyInterface<MyClass>>();

// returns: Implementation3<FooBarClass>.
container.GetAllInstances<IMyInterface<FooBarClass>>();

// returns: empty list.
container.GetAllInstances<IMyInterface<AnotherClass>>();
```

For more information, see the [collections section](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#collections) and the [generic collections section](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#mixing-collections-of-open-generic-and-non-generic-components) in the documentation.